# Auth in microservices: one session per user

Tags: authentication, microservices

My application consists of several microservices. I want to authorize which would allow:

1. perform authorization through the authorization microservice
2. log out
3. do not allow the user to log in from more than 1 device (i.e. if the user logged in from computer A, then when authorizing from computer B, make the session invalid for computer A).

I read that for microservices it is better to use JWT token. But it does not allow the implementation of point 3 (unless, when validating it, you do not contact the database every time, which makes its use not advisable)

Anyone has any advice?